# Probability of having at least one pair in a baccarat game?

Tags: probability, statistics

8 decks of playing cards are used in baccarat initially. In each game 4 cards are drawn from the shoe which contains the 8 decks of cards (416 cards in total), in which 2 cards for Banker and 2 cards for Player. What is the probability of having at least one pair in a Baccarat game (that is, either Banker or Player get a pair or both got a pair)?

Comment: Please give your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- Find the probability that the second card drawn is the same as the first
- Double that (either the player of the banker may have a pair)
- Reduce the result as both may have a pair, which will have been counted twice

  - subtract the probability they have the same pair
  - subtract the probability they have different pairs pair